# What is the first data that Wireshark displays?

Tags: networking, wireshark

The following image shows a regular TCP packet captured in Wireshark:

[image]

Does the data that I have marked in the image exist in the packet itself, or is it information that Wireshark has generated?

Comment: Expand it.  But Yes;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you highlighted in your screenshot is metadata that Wireshark is creating/reporting. It was not transmitted over the wire.

The next section, labelled "Ethernet II", is the beginning of the bits that were actually transmitted over the wire.

Answer (score 1):

The Frame part is related to the obtained data and is generated by Wireshark as a form of encapsulation of [2nd Layer](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_DataLinkLayerLayer2.htm) of ISO/OSI model.

The exact meaning of the Frame part in Wireshark can be found [there](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Protocols/frame/), where are described all the features

Answer (score 0):

This field is just a report that is created from wireshark. You can view informations about your data from this field quickly. This field can be thought as summary of the data that you sent over your interface.

Comment: I wanted to call attention to summary word and content of this file unlike the accepted answer. Thank you for kindness.